# Difference between .then() and .whenCompleted() methods when working with Futures?

Tags: dart

I'm exploring Futures in Dart, and I'm confused about these two methods that Future offers, `.then()` and `.whenCompleted()`. What's the main difference between them?

Lets say I want to read a .txt using `.readAsString()`, I would do it like this:

```
void main(){
  File file = new File('text.txt');
  Future content = file.readAsString();
  content.then((data) {
    print(content);
  });  
}
```

So `.then()` is like a callback that fires a function once the Future is completed.

But I see there is also `.whenComplete()` that can also fire a function once Future completes. Something like this :

```
void main(){
  File file = new File('text.txt');
  Future content = file.readAsString();
  content.whenComplete(() {
    print("Completed");
  });
}
```

The difference I see here is that `.then()` has access to data that was returned!
What is `.whenCompleted()` used for? When should we choose one over the other?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[.whenComplete](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/Future/whenComplete.html) will fire a function either when the Future completes with an error or not, instead [.then](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/Future/then.html) will fire a function after the Future completes without an error.

Quote from the [.whenComplete](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/Future/whenComplete.html) API DOC

> This is the asynchronous equivalent of a "finally" block.

Comment: They are not actual types, but [generics](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics).

Comment: Not actually... if you put `then` after `catchError` , `then` is called because `catchError` returns a completely new Future, indeed if were to return an error inside `catchError` `.then` won't be fired, in asynchronous code your code would be something like this:  https://gist.github.com/Hexer10/87a6f38616f74321c85f2f91a5450d4e

Answer (score 19):

`then` runs if the future completes successfully.

`catchError` runs if the future fails.

`whenComplete` runs regardless of the future completed with a value or with an error.

Here's the basic flow:

```dart
someFuture().then((value) {
  print('Future finished successfully i.e. without error');
}).catchError((error) {
  print('Future finished with error');
}).whenComplete(() {
  print('Either of then or catchError has run at this point');
});
```

Comment: You're registering a `Future.then` callback on the `Future` returned by `catchError`, not on the original `Future`.  That is, you're explicitly setting your `.then` callback to wait for `.catchError` to complete.

Comment: @jamesdlin Sorry, I was new to `Future` back then and thanks, I've updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

`.whenComplete` = The function inside `.whenComplete` is called when this future completes, whether it does so with a value or with an error.

`.then` = Returns a new Future which is completed with the result of the call to onValue (if this future completes with a value) or to onError (if this future completes with an error)

Read detail on API DOC

[whenComplete](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Future/whenComplete.html)   [then](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Future/then.html)