# How to call a function only once in a for loop of 'Firestore DocumentSnapshot'?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete documents from `firestore` using:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Data")
      .where('user_id', isEqualTo: uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {
    for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.docs) {
      ds.reference.delete().then((value) {
        print("document deleted");
        moveToNextDeletion(); // <-The function shold be called only once
      });
    }
  });
```

so once all documents deleted I wanna call `moveToNextDeletion();` function, but it keeps calling until all documents deleted (cause of for loop).

**Is there any way to call that function once all documents deleted?**

Comment: You will need to collect all the futures returned by each call to `delete()` into a single array and wait for them all with Future.wait.

Comment: firebase won't return anything when calling `delete()`, so I don't have anything to collect into an array!

Comment: No, `delete()` returns a Future. Your code is currently calling `then()` on one.

Comment: Thanks, @dougStevenson your comment was really usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop instead of for loop hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

use .whenCompleted() instead this method triggers when your prescribed operation is completed instead of using then.

[Difference between .then() and .whenCompleted() methods when working with Futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381236/difference-between-then-and-whencompleted-methods-when-working-with-future)

As far as I know .then() function returns an result from the job of previous function. Here you are doing an deletion operation. So you are not getting any results from the database.

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Data")
      .where('user_id', isEqualTo: uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {
    for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.docs) {
      ds.reference.delete().then((value) {
        print("document deleted");
        
      });
    }
  }).whenCompleted(() {
    moveToNextDeletion(); // <-The function shold be called only once
  });
```

I guess this will solve your issue. If it solves the issue then ping me I will explain

Comment: Even though if I use `whenCompleted()` it's still inside the for loop, therefore the next function will keep occurring until for loop finishes.

Comment: Can you explain me exactly what you want to do as it seems you want to delete one specific document in your database ```ds.reference.delete()``` and this line says something different. I guess you should pass the retrieved values to your reference ```ds.collection('data').doc(ds.id).delete()``` something like this

Comment: I wanna delete every document inside a `QuerySnapshot` so I'm calling a for loop to "read each document one by one to delete the reference of that documents", **The problem isn't with deletion!, I wanna call another function once  all reference deleted**

Comment: ``` FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Data")
      .where('user_id', isEqualTo: uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {
    for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.docs) {
      ds.reference.delete().then((value) {
        print("document deleted");
      });
    }
  }).whenCompleted(() {moveToNextDeletion(); // <-The function shold be called only once});``` try this one

Comment: Thanks man I've got another solution. appreciate your help :)

Comment: Can you share the solution ?

Comment: I'm sorry I won't be able to post an answer since this question is marked as 'Already has answers'. 

long story in short: **I added an increament counter inside the for loop once the counter matches with `document.length` I can call the next function**